# Non-progressive verbs with present perfect?

Tags: usage, present-perfect

Some grammar books/ [websites](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-use.html) say that 'The present perfect can be used for actions which started in the past and continue up to now...and often we use **Non-progressive verbs** (state verbs) in this way.' *For example*,

1. I have **known** john for years.
2. I've **been** there since 2011.

> 

3. I've **lived** here since 2011.
4. I've **smoked** since I left school.

The non-progressive verbs have been used in the examples 1 and 2. but, why are the verbs which are not non-progressive used in this way( like *the examples 3 and 4*.)?

What's the theory used when the present perfect is meant as an action which continue up to now?

Comment: There will be exceptions to any simple "theory" covering all such usages. For example, Bill Clinton could say *"It's true I have inhaled cannabis since I was a boy. But it was only once, back when I was a college student."* With no suggestion that he might *still* indulge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The website you link does not say that “Often we use “**Non-progressive** ... ” but that “we use **stative verbs** in this situation”. *Stative* and *non-progressive* are two different things.

   - *Non-progressive* means ‘not cast in the progressive construction’; a more usual term is *simple* (‘simple present’, ‘simple past’). The ‘progressive construction’ is that which employs a form of the verb *be* followed by a verb in the *-ing* form. None of your sentences employs the progressive construction; all are non-progressive. Progressive versions would be these:

     > 1a. <sup>?</sup> I have **been knowing** John for years.
     >   2a. <sup>∗</sup> I’ve **been being** there since 2011.
     >   3a. <sup>ok</sup>I’ve **been living** here since 2011.
     >   4a. <sup>ok</sup>I’ve **been smoking** since I left school.

     Note that 1a is marked as <sup>?</sup> *marginally acceptable* and 2a as <sup>∗</sup> *unacceptable*. More about that in a minute.
   - A *stative verb* is one which expresses a state rather than an event; *know* and *be* are statives. Other sorts of verbs, those which express events rather than states, are called *eventive* (or sometimes *dynamic*); *live* and *smoke* are eventives. *Live* is of the type of eventive called *activity verbs*: these are similar to statives in that they have duration in time and do not have a goal or endpoint ‘built in’ to their senses.  *Smoke* when it is used intransitively (*John smokes*) is also an activity verb; but when it is transitively (*John smoked a cigarette*) it is an *achievement verb*, one which has both duration and an endpoint (the endpoint is when John finishes the cigarette).

     One important distinction between statives and eventives is that statives are not ordinarily cast in the progressive construction. (This is apparently because the progressive construction is typically employed to ‘recategorize’ verbs of any type as current states, and statives are, of course, stative already!)  For instance, we do not say

     > <sup>∗</sup> I am knowing algebra.
     >   <sup>∗</sup> I am being a student at the University.

     In the last generation or so this rule has been increasingly relaxed in some contexts, especially in conversation, and it may eventually disappear. *Be*, however, is a special case. When you cast *be* in the progressive it takes on a different meaning: it turns into an activity verb meaning *behave*.

     > John is being a jerk = *John is behaving like a jerk*.
     >   John is being foolish = *John is behaving foolishly*.
2. The perfect construction is inherently ambiguous. What it ‘means’ is that the past event or state it mentions gives rise to some present state; but what that state *is* is left to the hearer to figure out, which may involve looking at not just the rest of the sentence but the surrounding discourse as well.

   In particular, perfects like *I have lived in Paris since 2002* may have either a *continuative* meaning (*I started living here in 2002 and I am still living here*) or an *experiential* meaning (*I lived here for a while at some point in the past after 2002*).

   One strategy for avoiding this ambiguity is to cast a perfect into the progressive construction when it is intended to bear a *continuative* sense: *I have been living in Paris since 2002* can only mean that I have lived there right up to the present. And this strategy is extended more and more frequently to stative verbs, exerting a force contrary to the rule against casting statives in the progressive. That is why *I have been knowing John for years* is now moving toward acceptability: it makes it wholly unambiguous that I still know John today.

This whole issue is discussed in stupefying (but nonetheless inadequate) detail at our Canonical post [*What is the perfect, and how should I use it?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §§ [3.1 Grammatical meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32) and [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

Comment: Once we *know* something, how can we cease to know it?  *I have known John since elementary school* means (to me) without any ambiguity that I first came to know John in elementary school and that we have been friends or acquaintances ever since. I don't see any room for ambiguity there.  If John is a very mysterious fellow, or is mercurial and is full of surprises, one might say "I have been getting to know John since elementary school."

Comment: @TRomano I agree; but the fact is, people these days often say "I've been knowing John" rather than "I've known John" in order to contrast with "I knew John". I would say it's because the PfPrg has become (or at least is becoming) the favoured form for the continuative perfect, and for many people that overrides the prohibition against Prg *be knowing*

Comment: @StoneyB Can you simply say how to differ *state verbs* from *non-progressive* verbs? (Is it because some state verbs can be used in continuous tenses?)

Comment: @Dinusha There are a number of tests which usually work; three pretty reliable ones are listed in the [tag:aspect] tag-wiki.

Comment: @StoneyB When the present perfect continues tense is used for actions which started in the past and are still continuing, Is it necessary to be doing the action at the time of speaking?

Comment: @Dinusha A continuous may designate repeated or habitual actions: *I've been drinking coffee since 1965* doesn't imply that I'm drinking coffee at the present moment, but it does imply that I often drink coffee "now".

Comment: *I* **have drunk** *coffee since 1965* -Does the p.perfect in this example mean that the action is still continuing? And Is it correct to use here p.perfect instead of of p.perfect continues?

Comment: @Dinusha The PrPrf ordinarily does imply that you still drink coffee, but the implicature is 'cancellable': in some contexts it might mean merely that at some time after 1965 you drank coffee. With the continuous construction that implicature is only cancellable to the extent that you might have 'just' (i.e., in the very recent past) stopped drinking coffee. ... You might want to look at [*This*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially §§ [3.1 Grammatical meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32) and [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

Comment: @StoneyB What about 'negative'? Does *'I haven't drunk coffee since 1965'* mean that I still don't drink coffee?